# How to view/tail the logs of CD stages from cli?

Tags: ibm-cloud, devops-services

I am working on IBM bluemix DevOps toolchains.  When my stages fail, I need to go into the Delivery Pipeline, in the UI, and check my logs.  Can I do this from the commandline?  I can easily get my app's logs (cf logs), but can't figure out a way for the continuous delivery stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no official way currently to do this that I am aware of yet. I will contact the team to verify this is the case and become aware of the feature request, so it can be considered in a future version.

**Edit:** I contacted the team and opened up a feature request for consideration. Thanks for the feedback!